# Search for all children in xml with php

Tags: php, xml

I would like to get all children and children of children (basically everything) inside of a node without knowing how deep the nested nodes go. I can use loops I suppose but I wasn't sure if there was a native function that retrieved all this data for me in one swoop.

Thank you I am using `simplexml_load_file()` in php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using, you may have to edit it

```
<?
$xmlfile="test.xml";
$reader = new XMLReader();
$reader->open($xmlfile); 

while ($reader->read()) { 

        if($reader->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT){
            echo "<br><b>Element:</b>".$reader->name;
        }
        if($reader->nodeType == XMLReader::TEXT){
            echo "   <b>Text:</b>".$reader->value;
        }
        if($reader->hasAttributes){
            $reader->moveToNextAttribute();
            echo "   <b>Attribute:</b>".$reader->name." <b>value:</b>".$reader->value;
            $reader->read();
            $reader->read();
        }

}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is easily achieved with a [`SimpleXmlIterator`](http://php.net/SimpleXmlIterator) which

> provides recursive iteration over all nodes of a SimpleXMLElement object.

#### Example

```
$xml = <<< XML
<node id="l-1">
    <node id="l-1-1">
        <node id="l-1-1-1">
            <node id="l-1-1-1-1"/>
        </node>
    </node>
    <node id="l-1-2">
        <node id="l-1-2-1">
            <node id="l-1-2-1-1"/>
            <node id="l-1-2-1-2"/>
        </node>
    </node>
</node>
XML;

$xmlIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new SimpleXMLIterator($xml),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST
);

foreach ($xmlIterator as $nodeName => $node) {
    echo $nodeName, $node['id'], PHP_EOL;
}
```

will output ([demo](http://codepad.org/hZjf6W6M))

```
nodel-1-1
nodel-1-1-1
nodel-1-1-1-1
nodel-1-2
nodel-1-2-1
nodel-1-2-1-1
nodel-1-2-1-2
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to stick to SimpleXML, as you can see in [the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php), theres only a method to [get direct children](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php). to get nested children, you'll have to loop over those and look for them - just like in `Exampe #1` you can see in the documentation:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement(
'<person>
 <child role="son">
  <child role="daughter"/>
 </child>
 <child role="daughter">
  <child role="son">
   <child role="son"/>
  </child>
 </child>
</person>');

foreach ($xml->children() as $second_gen) {
    echo ' The person begot a ' . $second_gen['role'];

    foreach ($second_gen->children() as $third_gen) {
        echo ' who begot a ' . $third_gen['role'] . ';';

        foreach ($third_gen->children() as $fourth_gen) {
            echo ' and that ' . $third_gen['role'] .
                ' begot a ' . $fourth_gen['role'];
        }
    }
}
```